# Need right-click on MacBook with Linux Mint 19 (Intel mid-2010)

Tags: linux-mint, macbook, cinnamon

<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> on a newly installed Intel MacBook (Mid-2010) often fails after installing both Xubuntu and Linux Mint; instead the Menu pops. I can't invoke a context menu to get to Properties and other functions.

I have tried two finger clicking using a different distro (Xubuntu 18.04.1 LTS), but hate it since I can't seem to accomplish it most of the time. How do I create a hot-key to give me right-click functionality? It need not use Command.

Comment: xubuntu is what I use fairly similar better support for some minor cases.  I don't have 2010 macbook pro so not sure if it will fix that issue.

Comment: @K7AA7 try reassigning a key on the keyboard to contextmenu or right click.  Depending on what you are trying to modify the files are located here /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/altwin /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc or /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us

Comment: meet me in chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hold down **Control**, then click for right click function.

Comment: A USB mouse is another workaround

Answer (score 1):

You need to effectively modify the corresponding file to `Pointer_Button3` depending on what key you want to change.

```
/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us
/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc
/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/altwin
```

The file point is to enable an accessibility setting that varies based on the machine you use.  Mint,Xubuntu,Ubuntu should all have this option.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/254375/how-do-you-enable-pointerbuttons-to-work-on-the-keyboard/254377#254377